# Creating an object in django

Tags: python, django

I have just started learning Django and I am making a database using SQLite
I have a python file called models.py and I am currently creating a py file for the objects called object. However I am having trouble creating objects in the database I have made. I think there is an issue with the object.py file because it is claiming that my FruitInfo sections have no objects.

```
models.py
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator, MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class FruitInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, max_length=30, validators=[MinLengthValidator("5")])
    name= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,null=False,decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator('200')])
 
    def __str__(self):
            return self.origin + " " + self.name

object.py
from stinky.models import FruitInfo
FruitInfo.objects.all()
FruitInfor.objects.all().values()

record = FruitInfo.objects.create(id = "A0001", name = "Pink Lady Apple", origin= "Washington State", price="$2.00/kg" )
record = FruitInfo.objects.create(id = "A0002", name = "Organic Bananana", origin = "Australia", price = "$4.50/kg")
record = FruitInfo.objects.create(id = "A0003", name = "Orange", origin = "Indonesia", price = "$4/kg")

record.save()
```

Comment: `object.py` is just a simple file, it will not run. This is also *not* the way to add records to the databa. You do this through a data migration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am currently creating a py file for the objects called object.

`object.py` is just a "simple" python file. Unless you load it somewhere, it will not run. But even if it does, this is *not* the way to construct objects in the database: this means it will *each* time you start the server, it will try to construct new objects. It also means that if you later alter that model, that you each time will have to update the logic of that file.

Typically one populates the database like that through a [*data migration* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

You can create such migration by creating an empty migration file with:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations --empty stinky
```

With *`stinky`*, the name of the app.

Then we can create data in the migration by altering the migration file to something like:

```
from django.db import migrations

def populate_database(apps, schema_editor):
    FruitInfo = apps.get_model('stinky', 'FruitInfo')
    FruitInfo.objects.create(id='A0001', name='Pink Lady Apple', origin='Washington State', price='$2.00/kg')
    FruitInfo.objects.create(id='A0002', name='Organic Bananana', origin='Australia', price='$4.50/kg')
    FruitInfo.objects.create(id='A0003', name='Orange', origin='Indonesia', price='$4/kg')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('stinky', '1234_some_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(populate_database),
    ]
```

The `apps.get_model('stinky', 'FruitInfo')` will fetch a model how it looks at that specific time in the migrations. This thus means that if you later for example add extra fields, then the records will run through that other migration, but the `FruitInfo` here will not have that extra field.